React Native - Avoid single package installation in podfile for tv target
I must avoid the installation of a single package in podfile for the tv target because is not compatible with the tvos (and I don't need it).
This is my package.json
{
  "name": "UFairTV",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "tvos": "expo run:ios --scheme UFairTV-tvOS --device \"Apple TV\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "expo start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "^3.1.2",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "expo": "^49.0.7",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.12",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.3",
    "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@0.72.4-0",
    "react-native-default-preference": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.12.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.8",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.19",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}

And this is my Podfile
source 'https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos-podspecs.git'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'UFairTV' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'UFairTVTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'UFairTV-tvOS' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  platform :tvos, min_ios_version_supported

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'UFairTV-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
  config = use_native_modules!
  # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
  react_native_post_install(
    installer,
    config[:reactNativePath],
    :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
  )
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end

The package to avoid for tv is react-native-slider.
The error is
[!] The platform of the target `UFairTV-tvOS` (tvOS 12.4) is not compatible with `react-native-slider (4.5.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: The platform of the target `UFairTV-tvOS` (tvOS 12.4) is not compatible with `react-native-slider (4.5.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.

pod install --repo-update --ansi exited with non-zero code: 1

I've tried many solutions but there's no way to avoid only a single package...
Thanks

In your podfile
config = use_native_modules!

is the line that takes care of (auto)loading the pods from your project's dependencies. Your project is targetting both iOS and tvOS, but @react-native-community/slider only has an iOS part.
You can still use this slider package for iOS only, but than you have to prevent it from being loaded for tvOS.
You can try the following steps:

Keep the following untouched in your podfile as it will still load all other pod dependencies:

config = use_native_modules!


Pevent autolinking for the slider package by adding the following to your react-native.config.js

module.exports = {
 dependencies: {
   '@react-native-community/slider': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,   // disabling autolinking for both iOS and tvOS
      },
   },
}


Update the iOS part of your podfile by manually adding the pod for react-native-slider and point it to the installed node_module:

pod 'react-native-slider', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/slider'


Do not add that last part to the tvOS part of your podfile. As a result, a pod install should no longer complain.

